# Buttons that doesn't appear when render

Tags: react-native

I followed a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILlHA2kIuxs) to add authentication in a React app with expo. The problem is the 2 buttons "Log In" and "Sign Up" does not display

Could you tell me why ?
Sometimes there is such problems when the element is not charged yet, but I don't understand why it would be the case here.

```
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: XXXXXXX,
    authDomain: XXXXXXX,
    databaseURL: XXXXXXX,
    projectId: XXXXXXX,
    storageBucket: XXXXXXX,
    messagingSenderId: XXXXXXX
});

export default class Login extends React.Component {

    state = {
            email:'', 
            password:'', 
            error:'',
            loading:false
    };

    onLoginPress(){
        this.state({error:'', loading:true});
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(()=>{
            this.state({error:'',loading:false})
            this.props.navigation.navigater('Home')
        })
        .catch (()=> {
            this.state({error:"authentif faild", loading:false});
        })
    }

    onSignUpPress(){
        this.state({error:'', loading:true});
        firebase.auth().createWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(()=>{
            this.state({error:'',loading:false})
            this.props.navigation.navigater('Home')
        })
        .catch (()=> {
            this.state({error:"authentif faild", loading:false});
        })
    }

    renderButtonOrLoading(){
        if(this.state.loading) {
            return <Text> Loading </Text>
        }
        return 
            <View>
            <Text> Loading </Text>
                <Button
                    onPress={this.onLoginPress.bind(this)}
                    title='Log In'/>
                <Button
                    onPress={this.onSignUpPress.bind(this)}
                    title="Sign Up"/> 
            </View>
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                    <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                    <FormInput onChangeText={email => this.setState({email})}/>             
                    <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                    <FormInput onChangeText={password => this.setState({password })}/>
                    {this.renderButtonOrLoading()}  
            </View>         
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its because you are missing () on your return

```
 renderButtonOrLoading(){
        if(this.state.loading) {
            return <Text> Loading </Text>
        }
        return (
            <View>
            <Text> Loading </Text>
                <Button
                    onPress={this.onLoginPress.bind(this)}
                    title='Log In'/>
                <Button
                    onPress={this.onSignUpPress.bind(this)}
                    title="Sign Up"/> 
            </View>
       )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Return the login in and sign up button view in a Round brackets

```
return (
         <View>
            <Button
               onPress={this.onLoginPress.bind(this)}
               title='Log In'/>
            <Button
                onPress={this.onSignUpPress.bind(this)}
                title="Sign Up"/> 
         </View>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have missed to add round brackets for return method.

```
renderButtonOrLoading(){
        if(this.state.loading) {
            return <Text> Loading </Text>
        }
        return (
            <View>
            <Text> Loading </Text>
                <Button
                    onPress={this.onLoginPress.bind(this)}
                    title='Log In'/>
                <Button
                    onPress={this.onSignUpPress.bind(this)}
                    title="Sign Up"/> 
            </View>
        )
    }
```